# GA4 client id issue

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

We are trying to migrate from Universal Analytics to GA4. The issue we are having is that GA4 requires a client_id field which we cannot get in a desktop application (C++). Is it possible to get client_id without a browser? and without being an IOS or Android app?

Answer (score 1):

Just generate a unique id for each user, that's it. That's exactly what GA does on web. Same applies for GUA. I wonder how you were tracking users without setting client id for UA. Were you tracking them?

Another thing is that despite all the fuss around GA4, it is an unfinished product. Even though Google recommends it, the professionals who actually work with GA's data recommend to either not use it and give it another year or two or implement it very shallowly in parallel with existing tracking just to have some semblance of historical data in it when it's time to switch.

Finally, if you're tracking a desktop app, you likely use the measurement protocol rather directly, so you mind find this useful: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase_mp#2

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Creating the random client id worked for us using UA but not with GA4. We tested it with the event builder and events are being recorded but users don't show up in real time

Comment: Keep in mind that GA4 is essentially broken. Barely usable. People have been arguing about bugs in GA4's realtime reports. Try waiting for a few days and seeing if you can see users in regular reports.

Comment: Yea, just verified it with a python script too and still same result. I will try again in a week or so. Have you used GA4?

Comment: Yes, but I'm using it either via gtm or via gtag.js. I've heard the measurement protocol in GA4 is still in active development, hence no comprehensive documentation on it, unlike the UA's measurement protocol.